# Comma seperated string input for postgres IN operator

Tags: postgresql

I have a source function that is returning value as '1,2,3'

and I want to use that value in IN operator but the format is not right and I am getting errors

```
select * from some_table where id IN ({some_var});
```

translated as

```
select * from some_table where id IN ('1,2,3');
```

format required

```
select * from some_table where id IN (1,2,3);
```

I have tried using type case and string functions but none is converting '1,2,3' to 1,2,3
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use `ANY` instead? `WHERE id = ANY(('{' || '1,2,3' || '}')::INTEGER[])`.

Comment: Awesome! if you can post this as a answer then I can accept and upvote it.

Comment: TBH Bergi's answer using a proper array conversion function is better than my hacky string concatenation + cast, just put the cast on the result of the function: `ANY(string_to_array({some_var}, ',')::INTEGER[])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [split the string into an array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) and use `ANY` instead of `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ANY(string_to_array({some_var}, ',')::INTEGER[])
```

Comment: This requires ::INTEGER[] conversion as mentioned by 404 above in the comment.

Comment: @hassan_i Oh, right, I missed that the `id` was an integer